# Why do I have big precision errors on GPU?

Tags: ios, precision, metal

I am doing a series of calculations on GPU that requires a good enough precision, but it seems I am getting a much lower precision than when using float on CPU.

For starters, when I load a value of `0.01` in a float buffer, it gets loaded as `0.009995` in the shader. Why is that? I would think `0.01` is a value in range for float vectors (using the `simd` library available for Metal).

Then, when doing a simple operation like this, the precision gets visibly worse:

```
simd::float4 p = simd::float4 { -0.04, -0.07, 0, 1 };
simd::float4 v = myMatrix * p;
v *= 1.0 / v.w;
```

`p` in the example is what I expect and use in the CPU test; on the GPU it is calculated as `{ -0.039978, -0.069946, 0.0, 1.0 }`, with one integer subtraction and one float multiplication by the already wrong `0.009995`.

What I would expect to get from `v` is `{ -0.010627, 0.006991, -0.034100 }` (calculated with the `simd` library on CPU, already worse precision than using doubles, `{ -0.010613, 0.006982, -0.034056 }`, but bearable).

What I get instead is `{ -0.010483, 0.006405, -0.044067 }`. This gets much worse with subsequent operations and the result becomes quickly unusable.

**Why is the result so different even if using the same precision** and why float data is not loaded 1:1? I tried disabling the *fast math* option for Metal, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: What methods have you tried for disabling fast math? I know of three but haven't used any yet.

Comment: @Jessy I disabled it from Build Settings under Metal Compiler Features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alas, it was not a precision issue, as the way I setup the test wasn't correct, so the GPU wasn't using the numbers I actually thought it used.

Answer (score -1):

You can't have `0.01` in float value because there is no binary representation. That is why `0.009995` was used. I guess SO already has good answers about floating point number representation in binary so you need just search.

Here is [good tool](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) for checking how float number looks like in binary. If you enter `0.01` you see this:

```
Decimal Representation: 0.01
Binary Representation: 00111100001000111101011100001010
After casting to double precision: 0.009999999776482582
```

Comment: double has twice the precision of what we're dealing with here, so that's not a useful resource for this specific problem. simd's and Metal's floats not yielding the same results, with fast math disabled, is the problem.

Comment: @Jessy My answer was about `0.01` problem and Metal's float or any other float can't store `0.01` because there is no binary representation for it.